# How do I enable Firebase app check for my android application?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I want to enable `Firebase app check` for my android application. I've learned that I have to register an attestation firstly. As **SafetyNet** is deprecated, I've decided to go for the **Play Integrity** attestation. Now, it's asking for a SHA 256 fingerprint? What is it and how do I get it?

Can anyone please guide me on the subsequent steps as I am a complete beginner?

Comment: SHA-256 fingerprint is something that's used to verify an identity. Steps on how to create one can be found on the github website, actually. I don't know much about firebase, but I am thinking since it's a popular site, there's probably tutorials out there to accomplish what it is you're looking for. https://docs.github.com/es/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Answer (score 0):

It's a unique fingerprint that identify an application, because Android requires that all APKs be digitally signed with a certificate before they are installed on a device or updated, with this Android will know wether this the app is secure or not

In order to create it you can follow this : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

There is also some relevant information here : https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9137403?hl=en
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider

Answer (score 0):

Go to play console. You will get App Integrity section and just click app signing then.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your app directory and open android folder. and then open a file called gradlew in the terminal and execute the command: ./gradlew signingreport

sha-1 and sha256 will show up to you.

If you ran into a problem you probably want to update the java sdk you're using. There's a 1 min video on Youtube that will help you out with that.

Comment: Can you share the link to the youtube video you've mentioned?